# JavaScript programming if cycle with two conditionals

Tags: javascript

I'm new in JavaScript. I need a help. This is a part from a course work and I have to display all dresses which have only one copy and only one size. When I the conditionals one by one they are working but when I try both of then together - nothing :D Can some tell me how to make the if cycle with two conditions. this is what I tried, but the button doesn't work.

```
if (x[i].getElementsByTagName("number_of_copies")[0].innerHTML == "1" && x[i] getElementsByTagName("stylist").length == "1") {
  table += "<tr><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td><td>";
  table += x[i].getElementsByTagName("stylist")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td><td>";
  table += x[i].getElementsByTagName("price")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a descriptive problem statement.

Comment: That must mean that both conditions are not true at the same time. Maybe you need to be testing for the opposite of what you are currently testing for in one of the conditions.

Comment: You have a syntax error in your script: `x[i]getElementsByTagName` should be `x[i].getElementsByTagName` (note the dot).

Comment: While `.length == "1"` will work, it's far more desirable to compare matching numbers instead of relying on `==` to coerce the string. `.length === 1`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I saw the missing dot and now everything is okay

Answer (score 0):

try === not == and also x[i].getElementsByTagName

```
 if(x[i].getElementsByTagName("number_of_copies")[0].innerHTML === "1" && 
   x[i].getElementsByTagName("stylist").length === 1 ) {
     table += "<tr><td>" +  
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td><td>" ; 
    table += x[i].getElementsByTagName("stylist")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td><td>" ;
   table += x[i].getElementsByTagName("price")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td></tr>" ;
}
```